# Kubernetes Java Client API(CopyfileToPod)

Tags: java, kubernetes

In Kubernetes Java client API, it seems that there is no support to copy files to Pod. There is one function in Copy.java called "**copyFileToPod(String namespace, String pod, String container, Path srcPath, Path destPath)**",I am using java client version:7.0.0, but it does not work. My srcPath was "Paths.get("hello.txt");" and destPath was "Paths.get("/usr/share/logstash/logstashvolume/hello");".The source file was not encoded. How to copy files to Pod using kubernetes java client library.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using [fabric8.io Kubernetes java client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)

```
try (final KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);
         ExecWatch watch = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withName(podName)
            .readingInput(System.in)
            .writingOutput(System.out)
            .writingError(System.err)
            .withTTY()
            .usingListener(new SimpleListener())
            .exec()){

        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    }
```

[Full example here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/ExecExample.java)